# Concatenate integers into a binary string and back

Tags: mysql, casting

I want to store 20 bytes, which come as integers from the application, in a binary string. This is the best I can do. Two bytes only to make it simpler.

```
create table t (bs binary(2));

insert into t (bs) values
(concat(unhex(hex(240)), unhex(hex(40))))
;

select
    conv(hex(left(bs, 1)), 16, 10) n1,
    conv(hex(mid(bs, 2, 1)), 16, 10) n2
from t;
+------+------+
| n1   | n2   |
+------+------+
| 240  | 40   |
+------+------+
```

Is there anything less verbose? If not how would the functions be to do those convertions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function to concatenate the integers into a binary string:

```
create function concat_integers_into_binary(
    i1 integer, i2 integer
) returns binary(2) deterministic
return concat(unhex(hex(i1)), unhex(hex(i2)))

insert into t (bs) values
(concat_integers_into_binary(240, 40))
```

Function to convert from binary string to integer:

```
create function binary2integer(
    bs varbinary(20), position integer
) returns integer deterministic
return conv(hex(substring(bs, position, 1)), 16, 10)

select
    binary2integer(bs, 1) n1,
    binary2integer(bs, 2) n2
from t;
+------+------+
| n1   | n2   |
+------+------+
|  240 |   40 |
+------+------+
```